# Generate a Ajax Radio List

Tags: extjs

I need to create a list of clickable radio buttons that gets generated through an ajax request. They will look like this:

```
10/15/2018
10/14/2018
10/13/2018
....
```

So I am doing the Ajax call below and getting the result:

```
onTabChange: function (tabPanel, tab) {            
    if (tab.getTitle() == 'Reconciliation') {
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: '***',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'data'
            },
            useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
            withCredentials: true,
            scope: this,
            success: function (response) {
                var selectReconciliation = this.lookupReference('lisatradereconciliation');
                // Get the data from Ajax Request and shape it
                var data = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText).data;

                var reconciliationItems = [];
                // Put the data into a shape that it will need to look like on the page
                for (var i in data) {
                    reconciliationItems.push("boxLabel: '" + data[i].substr(5, 2) + "/" + data[i].substr(8, 2) + "/" + data[i].substr(0, 4) +"', name: 'rI', inputValue: 'data[i]'");
                }
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                '***'
            }
        });

    }
},
```

Which then I am sending it to the view radiogroup item as follows:

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'radiogroup',
    fieldLabel: 'day',
    items: reconciliationItems
}]
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: You haven't shown how the 2 blocks of code are related in terms of timing. When do `reconciliationItems` get passed to the `radiogroup`? Has the request completed by that point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `reconciliationItems` array should be defined as a global variable, or outside of your ajax success handler, to achieve what you want:

Define the array outside of `success`:

```
window.reconciliationItems = [];
```

And then access it in the `success` handler like so:

```
success: function (response) {
                var selectReconciliation = this.lookupReference('lisatradereconciliation');
                // Get the data from Ajax Request and shape it
                var data = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText).data;

                // var reconciliationItems = []; <-- Dont define here 
                // Put the data into a shape that it will need to look like on the page
                for (var i in data) {
                    reconciliationItems.push("boxLabel: '" + data[i].substr(5, 2) + "/" + data[i].substr(8, 2) + "/" + data[i].substr(0, 4) +"', name: 'rI', inputValue: 'data[i]'");
                }
            },
```